# Riverpod trigger rebuild when update state with freezed copywith even if nothing changed

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-riverpod, freezed, flutter-freezed

I thought Riverpod will only trigger rebuild if the state value is different but turn out it rebuild every time when state is set although the value is the same. Is that true?

The case is as below

```
@Freezed(genericArgumentFactories: true)
class Model with _$Model {
  const factory Model({required int id}) = _Model;
}

class Manager {
  static StateProvider<Model> modelProvider =
      StateProvider<Model>((ref) => Model(id: 1));
  Manager() {
    Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1)).take(1000).listen((event) {
      ref.read(modelProvider.notifier).update((state) {
        var cloneState = state.copyWith();
        print("${state == cloneState}"); //This print true
        return cloneState;
      });
    });
  }
}

class TestWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  const TestWidget();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    var model = ref.watch(Manager.modelProvider);
    print("model change......................"); //print every second
    return Text(model.id.toString());
  }
}
```

It showed that the TestWidget was rebuilt every seconds but I thought it shouldn't as the state is the same although I set it again.
Am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about using `identical(old, current)` under the hood to compare states. `identical` presents for itself the following:

````dart
/// Check whether two references are to the same object.
///
/// Example:
/// ```dart
/// var o = new Object();
/// var isIdentical = identical(o, new Object()); // false, different objects.
/// isIdentical = identical(o, o); // true, same object
/// isIdentical = identical(const Object(), const Object()); // true, const canonicalizes
/// isIdentical = identical([1], [1]); // false
/// isIdentical = identical(const [1], const [1]); // true
/// isIdentical = identical(const [1], const [2]); // false
/// isIdentical = identical(2, 1 + 1); // true, integers canonicalizes
/// ```
external bool identical(Object? a, Object? b);
````

Here is a complete copy-run example:

```dart
void main() => runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));

@Freezed(genericArgumentFactories: true)
class Model with _$Model {
  const factory Model({required int id}) = _Model;
}

class Manager {
  static StateProvider<Model> modelProvider = StateProvider<Model>((ref) {
    Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1)).take(1000).listen((event) {
      ref.read(modelProvider.notifier).update((state) {
        final cloneState = state.copyWith();
        // const cloneState = Model(id: 1); //The print true in both cases
        print("${state == cloneState}"); //This print true
        print("identical: ${identical(state, cloneState)}"); //This print false
        return cloneState;
      });
    });

    return const Model(id: 1);
  });
}

class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    var model = ref.watch(Manager.modelProvider);
    print("model change......................"); //print every second
    return MaterialApp(home: Text(model.id.toString()));
  }
}
```

I modified the example a little, but kept the essence the same. Only by applying `const' can we achieve the absence of rebuilds.

Comment: This will not be correct, but you can apply the trick and determine for yourself when you need to update the state. Something like `if (state != cloneState) ` then update the state, otherwise do nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
May I know what you mean of `Only by applying `const' `? Where should I apply const.

Comment: For example, by creating such objects: `const Model(id: 1);`

Answer (score 2):

Riverpod by default doesn't rely on `==` but `identical` to filter updates.
The reasoning is that `==` can be quite inefficient if your model becomes large.

But this causes the behavior you described: If two objects have the same content but use a different instance, listeners will be notified.
It's not considered a problem though, as there is no value in doing:

```dart
state = state.copyWith();
```

Comment: Thanks. The key is `identical` but what I thought is `==`.

Comment: Is there any ways for us to override the identical function?

Comment: Not with StateProvider. StateNotifierProvider has updateShouldNotify

Comment: As well as AsyncNotifier and Notifier, which again use identical by default, but can be overridden with updateShouldNotify, and can also use notifyListeners as an alternate trigger.